# copy the elements of one array into another. unable to find my error

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
 int a[5],b[5],c[5],sum,i;


 for( i=0;i<5;i++){

     printf("Enter the elements of 1st array\n",i);
     scanf("%d",&a[i]);
 }

  for( i=0;i<5;i++){

    a[i]=b[i];
  }

  for(i=0;i<5;i++){

   printf("Sorted array 1 %5d \n",a[i]);
  }


   for(i=0;i<5;i++){

   printf("Sorted array 2 %5d \n",b[i]);
  }

  printf("\n\n\n\n\n");


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are assigning the elements of the uninitialized array `b` to the elements of `a` that you just read, rather than vice versa.  You need `for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { b[i] = a[i]; }` instead.  You should also check that the `scanf()` calls work and take appropriate action if not, but that's a refinement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Jonathan in comment, problem lies in this line:

```c
a[i]=b[i];
```

Since you haven't initialized array `b` you should not using it directly. If you try to print array `b` before this statement you'll notice it contains garbage values:

```c
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%d\n", b[i]);
}
```

I think for copying array `a` to `b` you should do this instead:

```c
for( i=0;i<5;i++) {
   b[i] = a[i];
}
```